# Unable to delete python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am attempting to delete Python 2.7 so I can use 3.6 and when I go to delete it from `appwiz.cpl` it tells me:

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run
>   as a part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your
>   support personnel or package vendor.

I have already deleted the path from the environmental variables.

Comment: Just delete the `C:\Python27` folder and use CCleaner to delete old registry files.

Comment: I'd note that it shouldn't be necessary to remove an older version of Python just to use a newer version. If you have the `py.exe` helper program (which is included with Python 3.6), it will pick the right version for you if you put an appropriate "shebang" line at the start of your files. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) for more details.